# Link a php file to an icon in a web application

Tags: php, html, icons, font-awesome

I am developing a web application. I want to use the download icon so that when the user clicks it, the file gets downloaded. For time being I have made a button using href.
I am not sure how do I put an icon to it.

Following is the code for the button:

```
<head>
<form action='expe.php'>
    <input type="submit" value="Exp" style="float: right;"/>
</form>
```

Expe.php is the file having the code which is used to download that particular page from the web application.

Code for the icon:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf019;</i>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make a download icon instead of just a submit button.

Comment: so, when does php come into play?

Comment: The word you are looking for is CSS

Comment: file having the code to download the page is in php

Comment: well you posted none of that ^ - I hope you're not asking us to write it for you.

Comment: `class='fa fa-download'`??

Comment: Aah nope. I have the code for it. It's just the code that downloads the page into an excel sheet. It is working fine.

Comment: Use what @Akintunde007 gave you on your `i` element, you are using fontawesome, there is no PHP here.

Comment: just wrap a link around the download icon.Then of course attach the `href` to it

Comment: hey @ankintunde007, the icon is visible. but it's just an icon. I want to put that icon instead of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Exp</button>
```

Comment: This worked. Replaced the "input type" with "button type". That's it.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `i` element with the `fa fa-download` classes as Akintunde007 mentioned in the comments:

```
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
```

And then wrap it with an `a` element like this

```
<a href="file_to_download"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```